# What to do when jayatana doesn't work?

Tags: java

I have installed jayatana but menus of the java apps (Intelij, etc) are still not in Ubuntu menu.

I tried to install/remove/purge/reinstall in many ways, the logs of the apps being launched show that jayatana is added to the java command. Finally I ran it explicitly like

```
java -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

but still to no avail.

So the question is if there is any way to diagnose it? Maybe enable some logs, pass a secret switch?

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-3.0-amd64:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-amd64:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-amd64:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-amd64:cxx-4.0-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-3.1-amd64:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-amd64:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-amd64:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.1-amd64:graphics-4.1-noarch:languages-3.2-amd64:languages-3.2-noarch:languages-4.0-amd64:languages-4.0-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:multimedia-3.2-amd64:multimedia-3.2-noarch:multimedia-4.0-amd64:multimedia-4.0-noarch:multimedia-4.1-amd64:multimedia-4.1-noarch:printing-3.2-amd64:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch:qt4-3.1-amd64:qt4-3.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

java:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
```

update-java-alternatives - not installed

Comment: Environment details may be helpful. Can you share the output of `lsb_release -a` and `java -version` as well as `update-java-alternatives -l`?

Comment: sure - updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ platform-based IDEs you can enable jayatana by using `Help / Edit Custom VM Options` menu and adding `-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar` to the end of opened config.

Comment: no luck either - it just opens the same ~/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/idea64.vmoptions

Comment: And it still doesn't work with that line added to idea64.vmoptions? 
Did you check if jayatanaag.jar exists on that path? I've been using jayatana with IntelliJ 15 and 2016.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04, and has always successfully enabled it this way on clean-installed systems.

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work and jayatanaag.jar exists.  But shuld it be actually added to the classpath? Or specifying it in -javaagent: should be enough?

Answer (score 0):

I added the mentioned file by hand in `[NETBEANS]/etc/netbeans.conf` like this:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m
-J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
-J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true
-J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar"
```

and also to `[ANDROIDSTUDIO]/bin/studio64.vmoptions` as a line entry.

Answer (score 0):

Add `export JAYATANA_FORCE=true` to `.profile` file in your home directory. And logout, login again. This works. But IntelliJ's search/replace inputs are disabled. I don't know why.